# Type mismatch error. found Array[String] requires Seq[?] in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Below are the code and the build error i am seeing.
Can you tell how can I resolve this error.
This is the complete code. URL are been omitted.
Spark version used is 1.6.0
Scala version used is 2.10.5

**Code**

```
import java.net.{HttpURLConnection, URL}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import java.util.Arrays
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType._
import scala.Predef.exceptionWrapper
```

object CoExtract {

```
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
//  val sqlcontext = new HiveContext(sc)

    import sqlcontext.implicits._

    val obj = new Connection
    val string_response=obj.getCsvResponse(obj.getConnection(new URL("https://")))

    val array_response = string_response.split("\n")
    logger.info("The length of the array is "+ array_response.length)
    val rdd_response=sc.parallelize(array_response.toSeq)

    logger.info("The count of elements in the rdd are "+rdd_response.count())

val header = rdd_response.first()
logger.info("header"+header)

val noheaderRDD = rdd_response.filter(_ != header)
logger.info("NoheaderRDD is"+noheaderRDD.first())

val subsetRdd=noheaderRDD.map( x => (Row(
  x.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1)(0),
  x.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)",-1)(1),
  x.split(",")(2)

)
  )
)

val x =subsetRdd.zipWithIndex().collect()

val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("Email",StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("Recipient",StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("rowid", LongType, false))


val rdd_to_df = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(subsetRdd,schema)
val df_to_rdd_again = rdd_to_df.rdd.zipWithIndex

rdd_to_df.withColumn("rowid", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy(lit(1))))
val final_df = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(df_to_rdd_again.map{case (row,index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Seq(index))}, schema )

val start: Int = 0
val end: Int = rdd_to_df.count().toInt
var counter:Int = start



 logger.info("Final Count" + end)
    logger.info("The schema of the dataframe is "+rdd_to_df.printSchema())
final_df.show(100,false)

logger.info("Schema of rdd to df" + rdd_to_df.printSchema())
logger.info("schema of final_df" + final_df.printSchema())

val df_response = sqlcontext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs:///")
```

logger.info("The schema  of the dataframe is "+df_response)
logger.info("The count of the dataframe is "+df_response.count())

}
}

**Build Error**

```
scala:48: error: type mismatch;
[ERROR]  found   : Array[String]
[ERROR]  required: Seq[?]
[ERROR] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[INFO]     val rdd_response=sc.parallelize(array_response)
[INFO]                                     ^
```

Comment: All the information is provided in ypur error console: string_response.split("\n") returns an array, but parallelize requires Seq, so you can just convert array_response to seq, while passing it to parallelize function

Comment: scala:48: error: value toSeq is not a member of Array[String]

Comment: show the code, because it is a member

Comment: I replaced it with the below code

**val rdd_response=sc.parallelize(array_response.toSeq)**

Comment: can you add complete code for testing?

Comment: I have added complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the `Array` to a `Seq`:

```
val rdd_response=sc.parallelize(array_response.toSeq)
```

Comment: scala:48: error: value toSeq is not a member of Array[String]

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: Scala Version 1.6.0

Comment: That is the Spark version. The Scala version will be 2.XX

Comment: Sorry my bad.
Spark version is 1.6.0
Scala version is 2.10.5

Comment: Hmm. According to [the documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.5/index.html#scala.Array) there is a `toSeq` method on `Array` so there is clearly something else going on here. Maybe try to simplify the code down to the simplest version that shows the error.